# Proper Docker container network isolation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

**Introduction**
I'm pretty new to the docker universe and apart from comfort the great advantage of containerization is service isolation. However, to my utter astonishment this is neither the default nor seems to be conveniently possible.

My scenario is actually a very common one, a reverse proxy (e.g. traefik) and some containerized services, some of which require internet access.
While being easy to setup the usual guides recommend using a shared bridge network between A B C P(reverse proxy).

**Motivation**
However, from a security point of view, this means all services are able to see each others on the network. If a middleware with forward-auth (e.g. authelia) is used for authentication, it is easily possible for one compromised service to impersonate another user on another service e.g. via

```
container-a$ curl -H "Remote-User: admin" http://container-b:8080
```

With something like arp-cache spoofing it might even be possible for one compromised container to capture all network traffic intended for another container.

**Goal**
My goal is to set up my container in such a way that even when one container is compromised, i.e. an attacker has shell access in that container, all other services are still secure. Therefore

- services should not be able to communicate with each others
- services should not be able to access local ethernet
- the docker host should be able to access local ethernet (I don't want to isolate the complete host from my ethernet)
- but services should be able to access the internet

The reverse proxy, as well as each service is set up with there own independent `docker-compose.yml`.

[image: Diagram of the desired network properties]

**Current solution**
I started by just disabling inter-container-communication (`enable_icc: false`), but this does not prevent the containers from accessing the other containers published ports.
After some experimenting I finally managed to achieve my goal by creating a separate custom bridge network for each service, i.e. a P<->A, P<->B and P<->C, e.g.

```
docker network create proxy_A -o com.docker.network.bridge.name=br-a
```

and connecting it to the reverse-proxy and the service. So the reverse-proxy's docker-compose looks like this

```
services:
  revproxy:
    networks:
      - proxy_A
      - proxy_B
      - proxy_C
[...]
networks:
  proxy_A:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
  proxy_B:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
  proxy_C:
    driver: bridge
    external: true
```

As long as the containers do not publish any ports, which they don't need to be accessible by the reverse proxy, this separates all of them and allows internet access.
If the service does not require internet access the network can simply be marked `--internal` and we are done.
However, if it does the non-internal network also allows access to my local ethernet. To block this I added the following custom iptables rules for all containers such as

```
# deny access to ethernet
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i br-a -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP # or probably better REJECT
# except for DNS
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i br-a -d 192.168.1.1 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i br-a -d 192.168.1.1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

While this works I am not very happy, as it requires a lot of manual configuration work for each service: creating a network for the new service, connecting the reverse proxy to it and setting up the iptables rules.
The only solution I could come up with to improve the situation a little bit is to create another `docker-compose.yml` which uses `include` to set up the proxy, all services and the corresponding networks.

```
version: '3'

include:
  - A/docker-compose.yml
  - B/docker-compose.yml
  - C/docker-compose.yml

networks:
  proxy_A:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: br-a
  [...]
```

But especially regarding the iptables rules I expected some way to add them to the docker-compose file, but I did not find any way.

**Questions**

- Is there a proper place to put the container-specific iptables rules, so they are always loaded when the corresponding container is started?
- Are there any better ways to achieve my goal, preferably all within the service's `docker-compose.yml` without requiring any further modifications such as editing of the reverse proxies docker-compose file, `docker network connect` and `iptables`? Just as it is usually possible (without isolation) by using traefik's docker provider I'd like to just spin up the new service container and be able to access it via the reverse-proxy.

Comment: You have several lines of defense.  For starters, consider putting your containers behind an API Gateway (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/design/gateway).  Among other things, the gateway can also serve as a proxy. Also, make liberal use of [Docker Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).  Here's a good link (one of many): https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Docker_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: PS: Independent of your original question, this is highly recommended reading: https://12factor.net/

Comment: Thanks @paulsm4 for your recommendation, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score -1):

I can only answer 1 question:

> Are there any better ways to achieve my goal[...].

Yes, there is. However, this is not in Docker. You should user Kubernetes or other container managers. These are inherently safer. Docker runs their containers as root. (Unless you are using Podman). This means, that if a container escape succeeds, they will be root of your entire server.

Docker is very manual, and managers such as Kubernetes (or using helmcharts) will help you a lot! (They are also much more focused on safety).

Hope this helps you a bit!

Comment: Yes: any "real" microservices application will have [container orchestration](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/containers/what-is-container-orchestration), e.g. Kubernetes, Azure ACI or Amazon ECS.  No: the process(es) run inside the Docker container should *NEVER* run as "root".  See the Dockerfile USER instruction: https://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/security/Running-Containers-as-ROOT.html

Comment: I was not talking about services in the container, but containers themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but with heavy container orchestration frameworks such as Kubernetes, I fear the extreme complexity which is in no way justified for simple web services for private usage. I don't need scalability or high availability. I just like to run a handful of services on a single server but benefit from isolation.

Comment: Usually these clusters are easy to install and manage. They do have a learning curve. However, if you think they might pose unneeded complexity, and it is for private use only, you will save time managing the networks yourself.